# sceneKit dynamic physic body fall through floor

Tags: ios, 3d, scenekit, arkit

I have a cube with dynamic physical body and a plane with kinematic physic body.When I place a cube above plane, it will fall onto plane and a bounce is expected.

The **PROBLEM** is: when the cube is small or light, it just go through plane.For instance, cube has 0.1*0.1*0.1 work fine but 0.05*0.05*0.05 sucks.In this case I still get physical body contacting notification.

this is my code for creating geometry:

```
//cube
//when dimension is 0.1 everything is fine
float dimension = 0.05;
SCNBox *cube = [SCNBox boxWithWidth:dimension height:dimension length:dimension chamferRadius:0];
cube.materials = @[material];
SCNNode *node = [SCNNode nodeWithGeometry:cube];
node.physicsBody = [SCNPhysicsBody bodyWithType:SCNPhysicsBodyTypeDynamic shape:nil];
node.physicsBody.mass = 1;
node.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = phsicBodyCategoryCube;
node.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = phsicBodyCategoryPlane;
node.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = phsicBodyCategoryPlane;

//plane
self.planeGeometry = [SCNBox boxWithWidth:100 height:0.01 length:100 chamferRadius:0
plane.physicsBody = [SCNPhysicsBody bodyWithType:SCNPhysicsBodyTypeKinematic
                    shape: [SCNPhysicsShape shapeWithGeometry:self.planeGeometry options:nil]];
plane.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = phsicBodyCategoryPlane;
plane.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = phsicBodyCategoryCube;
plane.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = phsicBodyCategoryCube;
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the `physicsWorld.timeStep` value?

Comment: NO, I haven't changed it.

Answer (score 1):

I’m surprised you’re getting collisions at all. See the [SCNPhysicsBodyType docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnphysicsbodytype?language=objc) – the kinematic type is for bodies that you move (by setting their position, etc) to *cause* collisions, but that aren’t themselves affected by other bodies colliding with them.

If you set the floor’s type to [static](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnphysicsbodytype/scnphysicsbodytypestatic?language=objc), you’ll probably see better results. A static body doesn’t move (either as a result of physics interactions, or by you setting its position), so the physics engine can more accurately check for other bodies colliding with it.

---

*edit:* Other things to look into:

- Use a `SCNPlane` rather than a `SCNBox` for your floor. (Note that you can create physics bodies with shapes different from their visible geometry, if that helps.) I'm not sure about SceneKit's, but it's easier for a lot of physics engines to check "has *some object* passed *this infinite boundary* since the last frame?" than "is *some object* inside *this finite region* on this frame?"
- Enable precise collision detection for your moving objects.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I misunderstood the SCNPhysicsBodyTypeKinematic. But when I try SCNPhysicsBodyTypeStatic, cube still go through floor.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found this is all about SceneKit's physical simulation. If the cube falls too fast, It will make a large penetration with plane In physical simulation steps. In this case sceneKit just let it fall through plane instead of collision. When I change cube's velocity to a small value It collided with plane.

My solution is to give cube a upward velocity when large over-penetration happens, which is the 30% of fall velocity. The trick is adjusting cube's velocity until a collision happens.

Comment: Hi, could you please provide some more information about how you solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Works only for spherical physics shapes**

For this issue `SCNPhysicsBody` has special attribute: [continuousCollisionDetectionThreshold](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnphysicsbody/3013743-continuouscollisiondetectionthre)

> For example, in a game involving projectiles and targets, a small
>   projectile may pass through a target if it moves farther than the
>   target's thickness within one time step. By setting the projectile's
>   continuousCollisionDetectionThreshold to match its diameter, you
>   ensure that SceneKit always detects collisions between the projectile
>   and other objects.